# How to convert cell object to an array

Tags: php, mysql

```
[    
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();


    foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {

        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();

        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
            if($cell->getRow()==1||$cell->getColumn()=='A'){
                continue;
            }
            else{
                $cell->$_column;
            }

        }


    }][1]
```

**Problem** : 
I need to get the values of `$cell` so that I can put it in a MySQL database , if there a good reference to get the methods of cell object?

Comment: Please add your code to the question, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: provide the code so we can help u

Comment: Okay I Edit it .. thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are libraries that make the cells of a xls file into an array and then manipulate and to store in a database to automate processes.

[phpexcelreader](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/)

example of this would

```
<?php 
require_once 'reader.php';

$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$data->read('archivoxls');

$celdas = $data->sheets[0]['cells'];  // obtains cells of file xls 

foreach ($celdas as $val) { // print cells
   print_r($val);
 echo "<br/>";
```

}